# In a MSBuild file how to I get the referenced projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a MSBuild script file and I want to perform an action for each projects that were imported in the file.

How do I get access to the referenced projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what kind of action you want to perform on each project. Assuming you want simply to print out the paths of referenced projects, here is the sample code:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    globalProperties.Add("Configuraion", "Debug");
    globalProperties.Add("Platform", "AnyCPU");

    ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection(globalProperties);

    Project sln = pc.LoadProject(@"MyProject.csproj", "4.0");

    foreach (ProjectItem pi in sln.Items)
    {
        if (pi.ItemType == "ProjectReference")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pi.EvaluatedInclude);
        }
    }
```

The code above uses [ProjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection) and [Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project) types from Microsoft.Build.dll, which is part of MSBuild.

Note, that in theory project references depend on build parameters, e.g. you might reference debugging library for Debug configuration, but not for release. Therefore while initializing ProjectCollection you have to pass parameters you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Actually I want to assemble multiple projects together in one final deployable package.  Normally the executable bin folder will contain averything however my "application" is actually a suite of executables that must be all packaged and deployed together.  I could simply change the target folder to bring them all together in a common folder but find it teedious and error prone and was looking for a way to automate this process.

Comment: @Newtopian, that is a different question from what you originally posted. Please open a new question for that.

Comment: true, I had a solution in mind which brought the present question.  I was just trying to give you some perspective as to it`s origin.  I'm still going to try it but I have posted the broader problem in a different question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113347/how-to-assemble-multiple-net-executables-in-a-single-application-suite-package in case a better solution comes up